# Incorrect answer in C program, what I am missing?

Tags: c, math

The following C program is for finding the value of formula (a+b)^2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
int a ,b , c;
clrscr ();
printf ("\n ENTER THE VALUE OF A AND B:");
scanf("%d %d", &a,&b);
c = a*a + b*b +2*a*b;
printf(" \n THE FINAL RESULT IS = %d ", c);
getche();
}
```

Upon running, when I enter the value for a and b as 1 and 88888, then it gives -688680271 as answer:

" ENTER THE VALUE OF A AND B:1 88888
 THE FINAL RESULT IS = -688680271 "

But the answer is wrong, it should be 7901254321. Please help. Thx

Comment: try with smaller input

Comment: Also, while it is not actually relevant to the current error, try *displaying* the input (`printf("a=%d, b=%d\n", a, b)`) to make sure they were parsed correctly. It wouldn't have helped here, but it's a good "first step" to debugging "wrong output" errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know that an `int` is normally only 32 bits wide?

```
88888 * 88888 = 7901076544
```

Which already requires 33 bits to represent. You have an integer overflow. Try using `long long int` as your type.

```
long long int a ,b , c;
// ...
scanf("%lld %lld", &a,&b);
// ...
printf(" \n THE FINAL RESULT IS = %lld ", c);
```

Comment: Tried. Same answer as before :/

Comment: @user3551432 Which compiler and OS (including the versions) are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `int` which doesn't have the range of output you are expecting Use `long long int`

Comment: Tried long long int. Tried. Same answer as before :/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're on a system where the precision of `int` is lacking. Your use of the vintage `clrscr()` function indicates this. Try using `long long` instead. You will need to change the I/O code to use the proper format specifiers. Also, you should check that `scanf()` succeeded before relying on the result.

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is called "integer overflow". Simply spoken a int has not enough bits to hold the number 88888^2. When you make that multiplication the result will overflow the limits of an int. When an int overflows the results are undefined; however in most cases you end up with a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

In Simple Words -int can hold upto 4 Digits .try long int or long Double.'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
int a ,b , c;
clrscr ();
printf ("\n ENTER THE VALUE OF A AND B:");
scanf("%d %d", &a,&b);
c = a*a + b*b +2*a*b;
printf(" \n THE FINAL RESULT IS = %d ", c);  
getche();
}
```

Comment: Any reason to re-post the original code without any change?

Answer (score 0):

use data type `long` instead of using `int`. the data type 'int' supports the values upto `32,768` only. it won't support `88888` because it is larger than `32,768`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the range of values that a data type can hold. This will give you an idea:

```
short int and int: -32,767 to 32,767
unsigned short int and unsigned int: 0 to 65,535
long int: -2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647
unsigned long int: 0 to 4,294,967,295
```

Accordingly, your variable 'b' should at least be long int and variable 'c' should at least be long long int. Below code should work:

```
....
int a;
long int b;
long long int c;
....
printf ("\n ENTER THE VALUE OF A AND B:");
scanf("%d %ld", &a,&b);
c = a*a + b*b +2*a*b;
printf(" \n THE FINAL RESULT IS = %lld ", c);
....
```